# Different results for Categorical crossentropy as loss and as accuracy metric in keras model training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, classification

I am training and optimizing my multi classification CNN with the following compile method of `keras`.

```
 model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                      optimizer=optimiser,
                      metrics=['accuracy', 'categorical_crossentropy'])
```

I used `categorical_crossentropy` as loss as well as metric to watch. After training the model for 10 epochs, I get the following values.

[image]

Evn though I have chosen `categorical_crossentropy` as loss and a metric, what can be the possible reasons for their values to be different?

Comment: Just a hunch (I don't know Keras that well), but could it be that one is the loss on the training set, and the other is computed on a distinct validation set?

Comment: Both are for training set here.

Comment: Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!